# Build a nested data class with lists

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-dataclasses

I am working on an JSON API-call and I wanted to build it using python data classes.
Since I am a beginner the solution may be cumbersome - in that case - please advise a more elegant solution.

So I want my JSON request body to look like this:

```
{
    "projectFilter": {
        "project": "all",
        "statuses": ["Finished"]
    },
    "currencyId": 0,
    "columns": [
        {"columnType": {
            "kind": "CostActual"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I have modeled this as a nested data class so I can change the API calls in the future.
Not sure if this a good way - as I said - beginner here.

```
import json
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import List, Dict

@dataclass
class _project_filter():
    project : str = 'all'
    statuses : List = field(default_factory=lambda: ['Finished'])

@dataclass
class _column_type():
    columnType : Dict = field(default_factory=lambda: {'kind' : 'CostActual'})

@dataclass
class project():
    projectFilter: _project_filter = _project_filter()
    currencyId : int = NULL
    columns : List[_column_type] = field(default_factory=_column_type)

    def to_json(self):
        return json.dumps(self.__dict__, default=lambda x: x.__dict__, ensure_ascii=False)
```

I get the following output when I call the `.to_json()` method:

```
{
    "projectFilter": {
        "project": "all",
        "statuses": ["Finished"]
    },
    "currencyId": 0,
    "columns": {
        "columnType": {"kind": "CostActual"}
    }
}
```

As you can see I don't get an array of the type `_column_type`.
I thought it would work since I have `columns : List[_column_type] = field(default_factory=_column_type)`
Where I though i specified the field `columns` as a `list` of `_column_type` and that I used the default object since I use the `default_factory` argument.

Comment: Hint 1: Does `_column_type()` produce a `List[_column_type]`? Hint 2: consider carefully the [example in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.field).

Comment: That said, your general approach looks quite sophisticated by beginner standards. I'm very much in the "duck typing works just fine thank you and I don't want to spend time on annotations" camp, but this is giving me reason to look at the new `dataclass` support more seriously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest checking out the [`dataclass-wizard`](https://dataclass-wizard.readthedocs.io/) library, as it seems like it'd be a perfect fit for this use case.

The default case transform used for serialization purposes is *camelCase*, so the good news is you don't need to pass any additional config to get the desired result when serializing an instance to JSON.

---

I started off by piping the sample JSON input to the included [CLI utility](https://dataclass-wizard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wiz_cli.html) in order to generate a dataclass schema, and ended up with a dataclass model strucure as below. Note that I went in and added default values for a few fields, similar to how you had it above.

```
from __future__ import annotations

from dataclasses import dataclass, field

from dataclass_wizard import JSONWizard


@dataclass
class Project(JSONWizard):
    project_filter: ProjectFilter
    currency_id: int
    columns: list[Column]


@dataclass
class ProjectFilter:
    project: str = 'all'
    statuses: list[str] = field(default_factory=lambda: ['Finished'])


@dataclass
class Column:
    column_type: ColumnType | None = None


@dataclass
class ColumnType:
    kind: str = 'CostActual'
```

Then I did a quick test to confirm that I'm able to load/dump JSON data using the dataclass schema:

```
def main():
    string = """
    {
        "projectFilter": {
            "project": "all"
        },
        "currencyId": 0,
        "columns": [
            {"columnType": {}}
        ]
    }"""

    p = Project.from_json(string)
    print(repr(p))

    print(p.to_json())

    # True
    assert p == p.from_json(p.to_json())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
Project(project_filter=ProjectFilter(project='all', statuses=['Finished']), currency_id=0, columns=[Column(column_type=ColumnType(kind='CostActual'))])
{"projectFilter": {"project": "all", "statuses": ["Finished"]}, "currencyId": 0, "columns": [{"columnType": {"kind": "CostActual"}}]}
```

Comment: Comments that just repeat what is already there are useless and when in one case it is *not* the same  (`Data`?) it becomes annoying.

Comment: @trincot good point. those were actually the auto-generated comments, and the class name was actually `Data` but then I renamed it to `Project` to describe the data a little better. I'll remove the comments, as you're right of course.

Answer (score 0):

The default factors just creates a single object of type _column_type and not a list of that. You can change that like

```py
@dataclass
class project():
    projectFilter: _project_filter = _project_filter()
    currencyId : int = NULL
    columns : List[_column_type] = field(default_factory=lambda:[_column_type()])
```

so using an unnamed function, a lambda, that creates a list with a single object to that type.

As a side note, in Python classes are named in pascal type so HelloWorld, not snail case as hello_world.